# What are good systems for managing Drupal infrastructure?

Tags: mysql, web-server, hosting, lamp, shared-hosting

I work in a company which is about to migrate most applications from in-house custom built Java/Tomcat applications to Drupal. Due to company policies, applications and websites need to run on in-house servers. This means that we need infrastructure for Drupal (PHP/MySQL) applications.

This must have been solved a million times already. I believe this is what web-hosting companies does every day. Even though we work on a much smaller scale than web-hosting companies, i assume it would make sense to look at the task as if we're going to have an internal small-scale web-hosting company. This means that the guys in IT operations could be "responsible" for "offering" web-hosting, while developers could use these "services".

We have three environments; dev(elopment), test and prod(uction). It would make sense that developers could log in to a system and create/edit/delete dev and test sites as they'd like. Production sites should be available through the same system, but only available to IT ops.

We need to work with clusters of web servers, meaning that an administration system should be capable of creating/editing/deleting sites across multiple servers.

I know there's no "this is it" answer to my question; but what would be a good place to start to get going with this? Apart from the actual hardware, what would be a good administration system for this?

Comment: Use an automated tool to do the deployment for you, like Chef or Puppet. Do not let developers or anyone else edit code directly on the server. Development should be done on an environment on the local computer of the dev and pushed to a version control system, such as git, then built into some artifacts deployed by an automation tool.

Comment: This means that you'd have to go through a manual process to create new sites though. If we need to quickly create a test site, this involves creating nginx configuration, mysql databases, servers users and the like...?

Comment: If you've properly set up puppet and written the appropriate roles and profiles, then it could be as simple as setting a class parameter with the hostname of the new service and applying the appropriate roles to the appropriate servers.

Comment: Also, do not even _think_ of using tools designed for the web hosting industry. These are difficult to support, difficult to scale, and generally only support very tiny web sites which are so small that many of them can run on a single virtual machine. This is probably not your scenario.

Comment: Take a look into Docker which basically provides exactly what you want. You can create images with PHP and MySQL being preinstalled and even Drupal already installed. Then you can easily deploy that image every time you need a testing site. Integrating it with Git or your Version Control System would also provide automatic deployment without reconfiguring on other hardware because it runs on the Docker Engine.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're dealing with Drupal many parts of your website configuration will not just live in code. This has been solved many times before, but I don't think it has ever been solved once and for all. There will be pain.

You can ease this pain by ensuring that developers are putting as much as possible in code, through [Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) and custom Drupal modules, but this is not going to cut it, by far.

More pain will be eased by using [drush](http://drush.ws/), which will make it easier to automate a large part of your workflow.

You should also look into using [Aegir](http://www.aegirproject.org/), which "allows you to deploy and manage many Drupal sites, and can scale across multiple server clusters".  Personally have stepped away from it though because it added too much complexity for what it actually does (for my use cases).

[This answer on Drupal Answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/21251/14067) contains some links to articles that discuss the issue profoundly.